# django-channels identify client on reconnect

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I connect several (anonymous, not logged in) clients via websocket / django-channels (routing.py, consumers.py). When a client reloads the page or reconnects, for whatever reason, he gets a new `channel_name`. Is there a nice way to identify the reconnecting client as the same client he was on first connect? Is there some kind of identifier?

Comment: If the client doesn't send any: no. The client has to remember their own identity first in some way, i.e. cookies or ids in local storage. Then they can send that identifier to Channels upon connection.

Answer (score 0):

If the client reloads in the same browser and you're using django's session mechanism, you will have a unique cookie (and therefore session) for each client. You have to save the session (in a view, not in your websocket) before it's useful, but that can be done on first page load.